# Maven Shade plugin Merge MANIFEST.MD

Tags: java, maven, manifest, maven-shade-plugin

I have a lib whose `MANIFEST.MD` file contains certain classpath entries. I use this lib in my Project & use maven-shade-plugin to make an uber-jar. In this process, the `MANIFEST.MD` contents of the lib are lost.

My Lib MANIFEST File:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: pankajsinghal
Class-Path: $JAVA_HOME/lib/ lib/commons-codec-1.9.jar lib/httpcore-4.4.1.jar
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.5.4
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_181
```

When I create the uber-jar, it creates its own MANIFEST file with new content:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: pankajsinghal
X-Compile-Target-JDK: 1.8
Class-Path: conf/
X-Compile-Source-JDK: 1.8
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.5.4
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_181
Main-Class: com.projectA.Main
```

How can I merge the lib's `MANIFEST.MD` content with the new `uber-jar`'s `MANIFEST.MD` file, so that the `Class-Path` entries of lib's MANIFEST are included in the uber-jar's MANIFEST file.

I tried with the following transformer:

```
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
    <resource>META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</resource>
</transformer>
```

But, the build fails with the following message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:3.0.0:shade (default) on project projectA: Error creating shaded jar: duplicate entry: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: You should use `ManifestResourceTransformer`...I guess..

Comment: From what I've read about it, it used to set some parameters in the newly created MANIFEST file. It doesn't provide anything related to merging MANIFEST files. If you can provide me with some example, that would help